# Snowflake "000603 (XX000): SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300010:3443530546; incident 4967615"

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-administration

I am trying this query below in snowflake to copy all the tables in my schema over to AWS S3, I believe all pre-requisites are aptly put in place, works fine for a single table copy with a standard basic copy into query, but for multiple tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXPORT_ALL_TABLES_TO_S3()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
DECLARE
  currentTimestamp STRING;
  filePrefix STRING;
  stageName STRING;
  databaseName STRING;
  schemaName STRING;
  tableName STRING;
  query STRING;
BEGIN
  currentTimestamp := TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MISS');
  filePrefix := 'file_' || currentTimestamp;
  stageName := 'Hiding_It';
  databaseName := 'Hiding_It';
  schemaName := 'Hiding_It';

  FOR tableName IN (SELECT MAX(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = :schemaName GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA) DO
    query := 'COPY INTO @' || stageName || '/snowflake/' || databaseName || '/' || schemaName || '/' || tableName || '/' || filePrefix || '.csv FROM ' || databaseName || '.' || schemaName || '.' || tableName || ' FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = ''CSV'')';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
  END FOR;

  RETURN 'Data exported to S3 successfully.';
END;
$$;

CALL EXPORT_ALL_TABLES_TO_S3();
```

Gives Error: 000603 (XX000): SQL execution internal error:
Processing aborted due to error 300010:3443530546; incident 4967615

I have seen such similar errors from various Snowflake users but what worked for others did not work for me, any help here is highly highly appreciated

Comment: FOR cursor loop expects cursor name (provided query text). `FOR tableName IN (SELECT ....) DO` => `FOR tableName IN cursorName DO`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, I tried this and no luck, I am no SQL guru so I may be doing that wrong, how would you arrange that in this query?

Comment: [Examples - Cursor-Based FOR Loops](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/for#examples)